# Framework7 is already initialized (React)

Tags: html-framework-7

Im using framework7 in my react webpage. While im working on my project, hot module replacement is being used. On first loading project works fine, but next i get following error. `Error: Framework7 is already initialized and can't be initialized more than once`.
So i need to check whether framework is already inited, but i didn't find any properties on f7 object ref. Also i tried to place `init: false` and `initOnDeviceReady: false` to f7params, but nothing help, f7 app stopped working, but error was thrown anyway.
What is the solution? Thanks in advance.